# Undefined method `acts_as_tree'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deprecated, acts-as-tree

I am upgrading a project from rails 2 to 4 but cannot find what is the equivalent gem for "acts_as_tree" for rails 4. I saw threads saying "acts_as_tree" is already deprecated, so am looking for another way to use this method in Rails 4. Thank you!

Comment: [`acts_as_tree`](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree) doesn't appear to be deprecated.

Comment: I already installed using 'gem install acts_as_tree' and then bundle install. But it still gives me the same error 'undefined method `acts_as_tree'

Comment: `gem install acts_as_tree and then bundle install.` because this isn't how you install a gem using bundler... add it to your `Gemfile` then run bundle install. After doing so, it should be listed in `Gemfile.lock`

Answer (score 0):

`acts_as_tree` is now a gem. If you want to use it - add it to your Gemfile

Here is the `acts_as_tree` project on github:
https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree

Comment: but why does the error say Undefined Method acts_as_tree?